# Automation in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: automation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am stuck in automatization my Functional Audit Table. Basically I am trying to automatize basic steps with no success.

It all could be called macro. But basically I was trying to fill information in one sheet (_Data Entry) and these information (columns ID, Function name, Group, Frequency and Users) copied to another sheet (called _tmp). On this (_tmp) sheet there the idea was to be done automated (as much as possible) these actions:

- Calculation. Percent recalculation of frequency and users based on columns E & F.
- Association to label in column Frequency (label) and Users (Label). I tried the Vlookup function that has to search value in column F (or H) and based on match in range from another sheet (_Settings sheet) it has to associate label from range in _Settings sheet. But it seems it couldn't associate label based on data range.
- Calculate the Function coefficient (column J in _tmp sheet). Basically for bar chart. Function is correct, but for "automatization I just copied it to 10000 row (I don't know how many values will be there). But this looks fine.
- Based on group match, I tried to write function (LOOKUP + MATCH) which will search the entire list (column C), find similar words from column C (called Group / page) and count the calculated coefficient (column J in that row). All these I intend to write in column Group coefficient - in column K the name of the group, in column L sum of the found coefficient based on group name match.

And based on _tmp sheet I was able to generate the Scatter chart (one for functions in front of Users(%) & Frequency (%), second for groups again in front of Users(%) & Frequency(%)) and the bar chart (here I am using the group and calculated coefficient columns). I found, that this have to be done manually. I was able on Excel to create graph where data range could be whole column. Google Spreadsheet seems to be the exact range.

I have something similar on Excel few years ago, but I tried to do on Mac version with no success. And also, main problem is that it is not multiplatform. I am sharing this audit with several teammates on different platforms - Unix and MS. It also seems that macros and functions are quite different in version for Windows and Mac (my old table didn't work anymore).

I know it is quite hard to imagine. So I made a copy of my report without all the mess that I done badly. Here is link to my table >

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VIYs75JNM0I-hDHK3WNK3WHxgXX5oIjZbgtxY1ic778/edit?usp=sharing

I hope it is understandable, I have only basic knowledge of Google Spreadsheets, so my tries could be funny.

Thanks for any ideas; I am stuck for a quite long time.

Comment: [tag:macros] is not about Excel macros.  It should be removed. By the other side automation in Google spreadsheets could be done by using formulas and Google-Apps-Script. Include the formulas or scripts that you already tried. See [ask].

Comment: hmm, maybe there is some misunderstanding. I wrote I have something similar in Excel. before I tried to achieve this state in Google Spreadsheet, but with no success. I also didn't listed in Excel topic (or I hope). I saw the How to Ask article and well, I don't know where is the problem. I ask about ideas how to automatise. I did several steps to hope to get report automated, unsuccessfully. So, based on your thoughts - for example instead of using VLOOKUP (or another function) I have to use Apps scripts?

Comment: No, I didn't say that you have to use Apps Scripts instead of built-in functions. I said that automation could be done by using formulas and scripts and ask you to include the formulas or scripts that you already tried. But forget that for a while.

Comment: Did you really read [ask]? 1, The title of the question looks like the bad examples in that help article. 2. The body doesn't include any code (spreadsheet formulas are considered code) and does not clearly stands what is the specific problem. If you need know how Google Sheets automation works, the question have a lot of unnecessary details. If you you need need help with each specific step, post a question for each one and include what you already tried and in such case if you used a built-in function like VLOOKUP include the complete formula sample data and a demo file.

Comment: Well OK, the name / title should be How to automate report in Google Spreadsheet in case of the help example? But that's the point that I am trying to solve. And the function I included in added link. But OK. I will remove it, this isn't much helpful. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case that somebody trying to find answer, I just found a solution. I made the whole sheet combined with functions:

IF (multiple IF in one cell),

QUERY (looking for range based on criteria, mostly IF),

ARRAYFORMULA (automatically copying data from one sheet to another)

Conditional formatting (just an output highlighting)

and COUNTIF.

It worked pretty well although that in every change in the sheet are all sheets calculated again. So, not good way for big amount of data. But I am now trying to make a something like button for start / stop calculation to manually override the automatic process.